# Why my get_queryset doesn't work when used on Model with OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello Django Programmers,

I have an issue which I don't understand.

Here is my model class:

```py
class Profile(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    employeeView = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

This class extends my User Model. Please notice that I'm using here OneToOneField in relation to User Model.

This model is serialized with that Serializer:

```py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 

    class Meta: 
        model = Profile
        fields = ( 
            'url', 
            'pk',
            'name',
            'employeeView')
```

And finally I have view which I use to process GET (list) and POST requests to the database:

**below view works fine (for GET request), but it gives me all Profiles related with all users**

```py
class ProfileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]  

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    name = 'profile-list'
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Because I would like to create view which could give me only profile for My user, I modifiet above view like so:

```py
class ProfileList(generics.ListCreateAPIView): 

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]  

    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    name = 'profile-list'
    ##queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.profile.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

But when I send the GET request I get this error:
{code}
'Profile' object has no attribute 'all'
{code}

So my question here is more general. Above view will work when I will use in my Profile model ForeignKey field instead of OneToOneField. In such case when in my view I will request for all objects which belongs to my user like so:

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.profile.all()
```

I will get necessary data. But how to ask for objects when we have OneToOneField? It seems that the procedure is different, but I can not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all()` implies that there are *many* related objects, so this is applicable for reverse one-to-many (`ForeignKey`) and many-to-many (`ManyToManyField`) calls.

In case of one-to-one (`OneToOneField`), as the name suggests, one object can be related to *only* one of the object of the related model, hence there's no point of `all`-like methods here.

Now, the `get_queryset` method is supposed to return a queryset of objects, not a single one. So you can not use `self.request.user.profile` as that refers to only one instance.

You need to return a queryset with the only instance of `Profile` that is related to the requesting `User`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Profile.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/ says that you would access the user profile by using user.profile. This makes sense, since it’s a OneToOneField and so we shouldn’t expect a QuerySet, just a single object.